# How do I convert Array of object key value to Object in object key value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to reduce and array of object(key-value) to one object(key-value).
I'm working with a json object injavascript

I have this:

```js
  "relations":
[
  {"609e598ad32e90519043f09f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593"},
  {"609e5945d32e90519043f09e": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593"},
  {"609e58b496d43235884e788f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593"},
  {"609e57e3e1560e58245544f4": "609d8de9575b49000466e358"}
],
```

And below is my expected result:

```js
  "relations":
{
  "609e598ad32e90519043f09f":"609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593",
  "609e5945d32e90519043f09e":"609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593",
  "609e58b496d43235884e788f":"609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593",
  "609e57e3e1560e58245544f4":"609d8de9575b49000466e358"
}
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to get the `key-value` and using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to store it into an object. Then you can assign it to `relations` property.

```js
let obj = {
  relations: [
    { "609e598ad32e90519043f09f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e5945d32e90519043f09e": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e58b496d43235884e788f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e57e3e1560e58245544f4": "609d8de9575b49000466e358" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.relations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let key in curr) {
    acc[key] = curr[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

obj.relations = result;

console.log(obj);
```

You can also clone the object and change only the `relations` key using object destructuring

```js
let obj = {
  name: "test",
  relations: [
    { "609e598ad32e90519043f09f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e5945d32e90519043f09e": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e58b496d43235884e788f": "609d8b78cf7bb100045fc593" },
    { "609e57e3e1560e58245544f4": "609d8de9575b49000466e358" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.relations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let key in curr) {
    acc[key] = curr[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const cloneWithChanges = { ...obj, relations: result };

console.log(cloneWithChanges);
```

Comment: One hour trying to do that and you in just a minute.... great. Any advice where find good info about Advanced array methods? thank!!!

Comment: Nothing better than DOCS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array